# Google+ button iframe error

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, google-plus, google-plus-one

I am working on a generator which helps in creating social buttons all under one roof. I was able to create generator for Facebook & Twitter but there is an issue with Google+ button at the very beginning.

I searched a lot but could not find a proper answer to "refused to display.... 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'".

**Issue**

```
Refused to display 'https://apis.google.com/se/0/_/+1/fastbutton?usegapi=1&action=1&size=medium…d=I0_1438276469698&parent=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost&pfname=&rpctoken=13424874' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.
```

Yes, I am testing locally but I even tried online on a website but it still throws this error.

**Simple Code**

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
    // GooglePlus script
    (function() {
        var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
        po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
    })();

    // Add button markup
    $( '#googleplus-container' ).html( '<div id="gp" class="g-plusone" data-action="1" data-size="medium" data-annotation="inline" data-width=""></div>' );

    // Initialize button
    if( typeof gapi !== 'undefined' ){
        gapi.plusone.go( '#googleplus-container' );
    }
});
```

Any straight forward solution to this problem?

Once this problem solved I will be dynamically changing the button and its parameters based on user input and then will be re-intializing the button so that changes can be seen live.

Is there any other approach that I can follow like directly adding the iframe?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `data-action="1"` from the `g-plusone` div. It's [not a supported attribute](https://developers.google.com/+/web/+1button/) and changes the behavior somehow.

Comment: Would you able to tell why `gapi.plusone.go( '#googleplus-container' );` won't work when changing the button to a follow button on change of a select option?

Comment: I am basically emptying the container div, then adding this `<div id="gp" class="g-follow" data-rel="publisher" data-height="20" data-annotation="bubble" data-href="https://plus.google.com/113914713777855840452"></div>` and then executing this `gapi.plusone.go( '#googleplus-container' );`. But it does not work. Any reason you can think of?

Comment: that's a separate question. make a new question.

Comment: Ok, was just asking. Anyways I think I found the solution. Follow button should be rendered using `gapi.follow.go( '#googleplus-container' );`.